# Securing Static Images/File with out File handler

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have website in asp.net on which user can SignIn and Upload images/Files/Pdf etc. I am keeping the File/Images on Server so Image uploading Time remains Low.

www.MyWeb.com/UserFolder/Img.jpg

My Concern is that when ever any user SignIn and View any image, the Image Remain in the Browser Cache. SO even if the user Signs Out , any One can access the images Still. by hitting 
www.MyWeb.com/UserFolder/Img.jpg

How can i secure The Image? There are couple of Posts suggesting to Write a File Handler but i want to keep the Image on Server and don't want to send the request when ever Image is clicked.

How can i Secure the Static Content that is cached in the Browser?

Any help is appreciated ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using IIS just secure the folder with forms (or windows) authentication and that tells IIS that it can only serve files as long as the user is authenticated. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771077(v=ws.10).aspx

The recommendation probably was not a file handler but an HTTP Handler, but that is a little bit too complex for your current needs.

For the cache, you always have the option to set the cache in the header of the web response from the server. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06bh14hk(v=vs.100).aspx

EDIT:

ok, for your escenario you explained in the comments I guess you are not using the asp.net engine, you just published the pictures folder in IIS as a web application. This is why you don't have any control on the rendering. 
What you have to do is to create a web page that handles pictures and then send a parameter for the picture, for instance: picture.aspx?id=picture1 and for example in the loading page you check if the user is allowed to see that picture (you already know the account because he is logged in) so if the user is allowed you just make a Response.write to serve the picture, otherwise you can say: Response.Write('You are now allowed to see this'). The idea is that you need a middle-man that is why you are using asp.net after all.

Let me know if it helps,

Comment: Thanks for Quick Reply , Even if the User is Authenticated , he would be able to Hit www.MyWeb.com/UserFolder/Img.jpg of some Other user.

The How can i relate a particular image to A Particular user only ? So who ever hits www.MyWeb.com/UserFolder/Img.jpg can't see it. But if a Very particulare user SignIn and Hit www.MyWeb.com/UserFolder/Img.jpg . he should be able to do that ...

Comment: You are right ,pictures are in the folder and i am just publishing the Whole web including Folder. I have got your idea to Authenticate the User when ever the image is clicked, and the The Picture.aspx would aunthenticate the User. But I have concern that If the Some user Simply Opens the Browser Tab, and write www.MyWeb.com/Images/UserFolder/Img.jpg and hit it . He is not going through by picture.aspx?id=1 , but he is going through as Separate user Request. Is is possible to Handle this case? when Rather User Doesn't clicks the image but simply write the URL to access the static image ?

Comment: ok, I understand your concern, what you have to do is to block the folder (do not publish it as a web folder), just keep it in your project, and set IIS as to not allow Browsing in the folder. This tells IIS that only asp.net can touch it, not from a web request like folder/picture.jpg , if any user does that request he/she will have a Access not authorized. and that solves your problem.

Comment: Thanks  Jorge Alvarado. 
This works upto Some extent. I create a Folder(UploadImage) in My WebDirectory that is published on IIS. I have set the permission not to browse the directory. This works if user hits www.myweb.com/UploadImage/ , and he is not allowed to browse the directly So till here every thing works great. But if the user Hits www.myweb.com/UploadImage/01.png, he is able to view again the uploaded Particular image. I want to secure the images at all as i have to make website that has to keep the dynamic images from user.
Thanks.